# QTreeView, QFileSystemModel, setRootPath and QSortFilterProxyModel with RegExp for filtering

Tags: c++, qt

I need to show a QTreeView of a specific directory and I want to give the user the possibility to filter the files with a RegExp.

As I understand the Qt Documentation I can achieve this with the classes mentioned in the title like this:

```
// Create the Models
QFileSystemModel *fileSystemModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
QSortFilterProxyModel *proxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);

// Set the Root Path
QModelIndex rootModelIndex = fileSystemModel->setRootPath("E:\\example");

// Assign the Model to the Proxy and the Proxy to the View
proxyModel->setSourceModel(fileSystemModel);
ui->fileSystemView->setModel(proxyModel);

// Fix the TreeView on the Root Path of the Model
ui->fileSystemView->setRootIndex(proxyModel->mapFromSource(rootModelIndex));

// Set the RegExp when the user enters it
connect(ui->nameFilterLineEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),
        proxyModel, SLOT(setFilterRegExp(QString)));
```

When starting the program the TreeView is correctly fixed to the specified directory. But as soon as the user changes the RegExp it seems like the TreeView forgets its RootIndex. After removing all text in the RegExp LineEdit (or entering a RegExp like ".") it shows all directories again (on Windows this means all drives and so on)

What am I doing wrong? :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got a response from the Qt mailing list which explained this issue:

> What I think is happening, is that as
>   soon as you start filtering, the 
>   index you use as your root does no
>   longer exist. The view then resets to 
>   an invalid index as the root index.
>   The filtering works on the whole 
>   model tree, not just on the part you
>   see if you start to enter your filter!
>
> I think you are going to need a
>   modified proxy model to do what you 
>   want. It should only apply the
>   filtering on items under your root
>   path,  but let the root path itself
>   (and everything else) alone.

So after subclassing QSortFilterProxyModel and some parent() checking in the function filterAcceptsRow() this does work as expected now!

Comment: any chance you could share the modification you did? I am hitting this exact problem now, but am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Sadly I don't have access to this project anymore. This is the mailing list thread: http://www.mentby.com/Group/qt-interest/qtreeview-qfilesystemmodel-setrootpath-and-qsortfilterproxymodel-with-regexp-for-filtering.html

Comment: I put my code as a new answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77972161/1414763

Answer (score 3):

I found this through Google and worked out a solution based on this thread (and other Google results). You can find my solution at:

https://github.com/ghutchis/avogadro/blob/testing/libavogadro/src/extensions/sortfiltertreeproxymodel.h

https://github.com/ghutchis/avogadro/blob/testing/libavogadro/src/extensions/sortfiltertreeproxymodel.cpp

One thing you have to remember (that's not mentioned here) is that child rows are not automatically fetched by the QFileSystemModel, so you have to call fetchMore() on them. In my case, we only have one level of subdirectories, so it's fairly easy.

If your code wanted to handle more varied directory hierarchies, you'd need to change the for() loop near the bottom of filterAcceptsRow() to be recursive.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fix.

As Strayer says, the problem is that the filter removes the root item. The fix thus ignores the filter for this root item.

In fact, QFileSystemModel appears to store every ancestor directory of the root. We thus would like to ignore these ancestors, too, to avoid further problems.

This is done by overriding `filterAcceptsRow()`:

```
class CustomFilterProxyModel : public QSortFilterProxyModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

protected:
    bool filterAcceptsRow(int source_row, const QModelIndex &source_parent) const override
    {
        QString root_path = sourceFileSystemModel()->rootPath();
        root_path = QDir(root_path).canonicalPath();
        root_path = QDir::cleanPath(root_path);
        
        QString parent_path = filePath(source_parent);
        parent_path = QDir(parent_path).canonicalPath();
        parent_path = QDir::cleanPath(parent_path);
        
        if (parent_path.startsWith(root_path)) {
            // offspring
            return QSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(source_row, source_parent);
        }

        // ancestor
        return true; // Always accept the root item
    }

    const QFileSystemModel* sourceFileSystemModel() const {
        auto* model =  sourceModel();
        return dynamic_cast<const QFileSystemModel*>(model);
    }
};
```

`CustomFilterProxyModel` is the actual proxy model class you will use.

`canonicalPath()` resolves symlinks and gives the absolute path.
`QDir::cleanPath()` normalizes the directory separator.

One problem is the case sensitivity of file names. Linux is strict while macOS and Windows are not. I doubt case sensitivity will be a problem when using a tree view. (Also, `QFileSystemModel` doesn't work with `QListView`.) So this is likely a solid solution. Too bad, Qt doesn't doesn't provide support for checking file identities, which would be handy in cases like this...